# check if user first visit on app with react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and I want to show new users illustration of how my app work.
how can I achieve that?

Am I need to download something from npm?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? From what I understand you want to know if the user has visited your app before. Is that correct?

Comment: @SanilKhurana Yes

Answer (score 3):

You may use AsyncStorage for that. AsyncStorage is an unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of LocalStorage.

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

const tutorialShown = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('@myApp:TUTORIAL_SHOWN');
}

// somewhere in your render method
if (!tutorialShown()) {
  return <Tutorial />
}

//somewhere in your Tutorial's componentDidMount
AsyncStorage.setItem('@myApp:TUTORIAL_SHOWN')
```

Details: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Comment: what I need to set as @myApp. And in this link, they say that it deprecated

Comment: @Nikasmusicandgaming as far as I get it it's just a namespace, so you may pick your app's name.

Comment: I guess you'll need to install it as a package (`@react-native-community/async-storage`). It's not a part of the core anymore.